# Can somebody provide me with an example for a sequence which has all integer numbers as limits points.

Tags: limits

Can somebody provide me with an example for a sequence which has as limits points the set $Z$.

*Because $Z$ is a closed set than it can be the set of all the limits points.*

Comment: $[0,-1,0,1,-2,-1,0,1,2,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots]$

Comment: Any enumerationof the rationals. Or do you also mean that it should only have the integers as limit points?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos the set of limit points is the whole real line, not EXCLUSIVELY the integers.

Comment: @TitoEliatron: Yes, I noticed that the text sounds more like it should exclusively be the integers, while the title might allow for other limit points. I asked for clarification the moment before I saw your comment

Answer (score 0):

Basically if $\varphi$ is any bijection between $\mathbb N^2$ and $\mathbb N$ then calling $\varphi^{-1}(n)=(n_1,n_2)$

We get that $x_n=n_1+\dfrac 1{n_2}$ will have all natural numbers as accumulations points.

It is not too hard to adapt it to negative numbers (split for instance odd/even $\mapsto$ negative/positive).

For instance $\varphi^{-1}(n)=\bigg(\min(n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2,\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)\quad,\quad2\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-\max(n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2,\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)\bigg)$

--> see this post [How to show that $\max(a,b)^2+\max(a,b)+a-b$ is bijective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3941754/399263)

But there are others like Cantor-pairing function and such, it just happens I had this one above at hand...